# Load dynamic content using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, prestashop

I'm trying to load dynamic images in my prestashop product page using jquery.

Is it possible to load `{$product.cover.bySize.large_default.url}` using src in jquery file?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `src` of the image dynamically.

`<img data-src="{$product.cover.bySize.large_default.url}" src="loading.gif" />`

Loop on each image and update the source:

```
$('img[data-src]').each(function(){
 var src = $(this).data('src');
 $(this).attr('src',src');
})
```